# While loop not changing to False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In my game I have a mainloop variable that while it runs does the main part of the game and when the game is over it should change to False. I have tried to implement it so when my lives are out another loop while start. In that loop there's a button that should turn the mainloop back on but because it never turns to false I can't turn it back on.

```
MainLoop = True
while MainLoop:
    # Setting fps
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            MainLoop = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                MainLoop = False
    # Getting keys pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #Walking controls for player
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > 0:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.vel - man.width:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.left = False
        man.right = True
    else:
        man.left = False
        man.right = False
        man.walkCount = 0

    redrawgamewindow()

    for rockk in my_list:
        rockk.draw(win)
        rockk.move()
    #Controlling man lives and game over screen
    if man.hit == 1:
        man.lives -=1
    elif man.hit ==2:
        man.lives -=1
    elif man.lives <= 0:
        Mainloop = False
        GameOver = True
    collided(rockk.x, rockk.y, man.x, man.y)
    pygame.display.flip()
    print (GameOver)
    print (MainLoop)
while GameOver:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameOver = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                GameOver = False



    win.blit(GameO, (0, 0))
    button1 = pygame.Rect(200, 400, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, [255, 0, 0], button1)
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_pos = event.pos
        if button1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            print ('amazing ')
    Text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Restart?", Text)
    TextRect.center = ((250), (425))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get stuck in the loop getting pygame.events.
You have break out of this loop bfore you can break out of the outer loop.

Please try:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            MainLoop = False
            break
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                MainLoop = False
            break
    if not MainLoop:
        break
```

Please also change the following section

```
while GameOver:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameOver = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                GameOver = False
```

to

```
while GameOver:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameOver = False
            break
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                GameOver = False
                break
```

Comment: Why do people who downvote never explain the reason?

How shall I improve?

Comment: pls retry. I enhanced the answer. There was another section where you have to break out

Comment: Did you retry after changing the `while GameOver:` loop?